# Что происходит в данном коде?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<button onclick="loadPhones()" id="button">Загрузить phones.json!</button>

<ul id="list"></ul>


<script>
    function loadPhones() {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('GET', 'phones.json', true);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;

            button.innerHTML = 'Готово!';

            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                // обработать ошибку
                alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
            } else {
                // вывести результат
                try {
                    var phones = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                } catch (e) {
                    alert("Некорректный ответ " + e.message);
                }
                showPhones(phones);
            }

        };

        xhr.send();

        button.innerHTML = 'Загружаю...';
        button.disabled = true;
    }

    function showPhones(phones) {

        phones.forEach(function (phone) {
            var li = list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
            li.innerHTML = phone.name;
        });

    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Привет

Начал изучать аякс и сразу непонятки. Может кто по шагам объяснить, что мы тут делаем?

Comment: откуда это? почему именно этот код? разбейте по строкам, закомментируйте, удаляйте, добавляйте, переписывайте, перезапускайте - чего вы хотите в конечном результате?!

Comment: ну так изучайте дальше, недостаточно видимо изучили.

Comment: @titov_andrei нашёл на learn.javascript

Comment: @Jean-Claude конечно, недостаточно)буду

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На странице выводится кнопка `button`:

```
<button onclick="loadPhones()" id="button">Загрузить phones.json!</button>
```

По нажатию на неё срабатывает событие onclick. Событие инициирует вызов javascript-функции `loadPhones`. Далее смотрим что делает функция `loadPhones`.

---

В функции создаём экземпляр объекта `XMLHttpRequest` в переменной `xhr`. Это и есть объект, который позволяет выполнять ajax-запросы:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Указываем объекту, что мы будем запрашивать url "phones.json" http-методом GET.

```
xhr.open('GET', 'phones.json', true);
```

В `onreadystatechange` указываем действия, которые будут выполняться при каждом изменении состояния готовности объекта `xhr` (readyState).

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
```

Всего имеется 5 состояний объекта XMLHttpRequest от 0 до 4:

> 0: запрос не инициализирован
>   1: установлено соединение с сервером
>   2: запрос получен
>   3: обработка запроса
>   4: запрос завершен и ответ готов

В этом коде указано, что если запрос еще не завершён, то мы ничего не делаем - делаем return (т.е. возврат из функции).

```
if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
```

Если сервер ответил с http-кодом != 200, то летит js alert (типо такая обработка ошибок):

```
if (xhr.status != 200) {
      // обработать ошибку
      alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
```

Следующий код выполняется если только status==200 и state==4. Ожидается, что сервер будет возвращать ответ в формате `json`.

```
// вывести результат
try {
    var phones = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
} catch (e) {
            alert("Некорректный ответ " + e.message);
}
```

Если вдруг сервер вернул ответ не в json или мы не смогли распарсить json, то вылетит exception, который сразу же словится в блоке `catch` и на экран будет выведен alert.

Если же всё прошло ок, то будет выполнена функция showPhones:

```
showPhones(phones);
```

Которая каждый телефон вставит в новый `<li>` в блоке `<ul>`:

```
phones.forEach(function (phone) {
    var li = list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    li.innerHTML = phone.name;
});
```

---

Непосредственно отправка ajax-запроса:

```
xhr.send();
```

Тут, думаю, понятно, что при клике по кнопке заменяется имя кнопки и блокируются повторные нажатия:

```
button.innerHTML = 'Загружаю...'; 
button.disabled = true;
```

Там где у вас:

```
// вывести результат
```

По-хорошему, должно быть всё возвращено назад:

```
button.innerHTML = 'Загружено!'; 
button.disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> <button onclick="loadPhones()" id="button">Загрузить phones.json!</button>
> ```

При нажатии на кнопку вызывается функция `loadPhones`.

> ```
> var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
> xhr.open('GET', 'phones.json', true);
> xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
> ...
> }
> ```

Формируем **асинхронный** запрос к серверу (браузер не ждет выполнения запроса) для получения файла `phones.json` и подключаем обработчик события изменения состояния запроса. Эта анонимная функция будет вызвана автоматически при изменении состояний запроса.

> ```
> xhr.send();
> ```

Выполняем запрос к серверу, при этом функция `send()` не останавливает выполнение скрипта.

> ```
> button.innerHTML = 'Загружаю...';
> button.disabled = true;
> ```

Меняем текст кнопки и запрещаем её.

Теперь вернёмся к обработчику состояний запроса.

> ```
> if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
> ```

Проверяем свойство `readyState`. Нас интересует состояние `4 - DONE`. Если мы его получили то запрос завершил свою работу. Вообще это свой свойсво может принимать следующие значения:

- 0 - UNSENT
- 1 - OPENED
- 2 - HEADERS_RECEIVED
- 3 - LOADING
- 4 - DONE

Их назначение можно найти в документации, например [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) или [тут](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp).

> ```
> if (xhr.status != 200) {
>   // обработать ошибку
>   alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
> } else {
> ```

Это проверка кода ответа сервера. Если код != 200, то выдаем сообщение об ошибке.

> ```
> var phones = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
> showPhones(phones);
> ```

Делаем разбор ответа, преобразовываем его в массив объектов, при этом разбор JSON строки заключаем в обработчик исключений. Ну и выводим результат запроса.

> ```
> phones.forEach(function (phone) {
>   var li = list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
>   li.innerHTML = phone.name;
> });
> ```

Это собственно и есть конечная визуализация результата запроса. Тут мы для каждого элемента массива `phones` создаётся элемент html-разметки `li` с названием телефона и вставляем его, как дочерний элемент списка `<ul id="list"></ul>`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Обязательно все просмотрю